# My program skips any digit that ends with a 9

Tags: c++

When I build it and run I noticed that my program sets dig1 to 0 as soon as it hits 9. So the output looks like this: 00, 01... 08, 10.
I searched on stackoverflow and cplusplus.com for a possible solution but I couldn't find it.

Here's the code in question:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int i;
    char dig1 = '0', dig2 = '0';
    cout << dig2 << dig1 << endl;
    
    for(i = 0; i < 90; i++)
    {
        dig1++;
        if(dig1 == '9')
        {
            dig1 = '0';
            dig2++;
        }
        cout << dig2 << dig1 << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, that is what you coded, so why are you surprised? Did you mean to put the whole `if(dig1 == '9')` block after the `cout` line?

Comment: No, I want to make it so that it doesn't skip it but I couldn't figure out a solution. I want it to include output that includes 09,19, 29, 39, 49...99

Comment: Putting the block after the `cout` would do exactly that, so I don't understand what you are trying to say with your comment

Comment: @M3lon *I searched on stackoverflow and cplusplus.com for a possible solution* -- So you expected to find a solution to your exact programming assignment by doing web searches?  Good luck with that, since that is not the way to solve programming logic issues -- you solve them by inspecting your code and writing the correct logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `(dig1=='9')` with `(dig1>'9')` as in

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int i;
    char dig1 = '0', dig2 = '0';
    
    for(i = 0; i < 90; i++)
    {
        cout << dig2 << dig1 << endl;
        dig1++;
        if(dig1 > '9')
        {
            dig1 = '0';
            dig2++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/TMbjbzsE1

Produces:

```
00
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
13
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to check the value of `dig1` *before* you increment it, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char dig1 = '0', dig2 = '0';
    cout << dig2 << dig1 << endl;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 90; ++i)
    {
        if (dig1 == '9')
        {
            dig1 = '0';
            dig2++;
        }
        else
        {
            dig1++; // <-- move it down here
        }
        cout << dig2 << dig1 << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, there is an alternative way to implement this - use a single `int` instead of 2 `char`s, and simply ask `std::cout` to pad the integer value with leading zeros when needed, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int value = 0;

    while (value <= 90)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << setfill('0') << value++ << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int value = 0;
    
    while (value < 10)
    {
        cout << setw(2) << setfill('0') << value++ << endl;
    }

    while (value <= 90)
    {
        cout << value++ << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so fair warning, I don't know C++, and I found this by accidentally clicking the homepage. However, I did tamper with your code for fun, and found the solution (:D).

Your issue is that before your logging the number, your changing it to the next value with your `if()` statement.

The solution I came up with was to just log it again before updating it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    int i;
    char dig1 = '0', dig2 = '0';
    cout << dig2 << dig1 << endl;
    
    for(i = 0; i < 90; i++)
    {
        if(dig1 == '9')
        {
            cout << dig2 << dig1 << endl;
            dig1 = '0';
            dig2++;
        }
        
        cout << dig2 << dig1 << endl;
        dig1++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This will end up printing out more lines than the original code, so it changes the behavior to something that may not be intended

Comment: Oh I see! Will definitely refer to this later when I learn C++.